# Unzipping files in perl with wildcard file name

Tags: perl

I am using the Archive::Zip module to extract a specific file.

```
my $file = shift
my $zip = Archive::Zip->('zipped.zip');
$zip->extractMember($file.'txt');
```

The problem is that sometimes the complete file name is not known, and I want to do something like this:

```
$zip->extractMember($file.*.'txt');
```

I searched around online and can't find anything for this module (or any similar module). Is there a module that allows for wildcarding in file extraction?

Comment: Have you considered calling the `extractTree()` method with no arguments to extract all the files at once? You could also call `members()` or `membersMatching()` to filter out what you're interested in, and then extract them individually like you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you could use the [documented](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip) `membersMatching($regex)` method:

```
my @files = $zip->membersMatching(qr/$file.*\.txt/);
$zip->extractMember($_) for @files;
```